# How to dynamicallty create multiple controls at runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to add multiple labels to a userform at runtime

It's for the player names of a board game; and until the game starts the number of players are not known. I have managed to figure out for myself how to use the dynamic array function to create the list of players. I used a For.....Next loop to add the player names. I thought I could do that to add the labels to the form, but it only adds one. Depending on where the new control type is declared, it either adds the first player only, or the last player

This code produces one label only within the groupbox, the last player

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Players_Num As Integer = InputBox("Enter the number of players")
        Dim Players(Players_Num) As String
        Dim newText As New Label

        For i = 0 To Players_Num - 1
            Players(i) = InputBox("Enter player name")
        Next

        'This piece of code was jsut for me to test that I was successfully using a For...Loop
        'to add the players names, and will be deleted later on
        For x = 0 To Players_Num - 1
            MessageBox.Show(Players(x))
        Next

        For z = 0 To Players_Num - 1
            newText.Name = "txt" & Players(z)
            newText.Text = Players(z)
            newText.Size = New Size(170, 20)
            newText.Location = New Point(12 + 5, 12 + 5)
            GroupBox1.Controls.Add(newText)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

This one places only the first player

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Players_Num As Integer = InputBox("Enter the number of players")
        Dim Players(Players_Num) As String

        For i = 0 To Players_Num - 1
            Players(i) = InputBox("Enter player name")
        Next

        'This piece of code was jsut for me to test that I was successfully using a For...Loop
        'to add the players names, and will be deleted later on
        For x = 0 To Players_Num - 1
            MessageBox.Show(Players(x))
        Next

        For z = 0 To Players_Num - 1
            Dim newText As New Label
            newText.Name = "txt" & Players(z)
            newText.Text = Players(z)
            newText.Size = New Size(170, 20)
            newText.Location = New Point(12 + 5, 12 + 5)
            GroupBox1.Controls.Add(newText)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've tried this in vs 2015 and 2019 Community

Where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the code, you are correctly creating the controls but their location is the same for all of them, essentially, they are being place one of top of the other, the first is hidden with the second, which is hidden with the third.

The line

```
newText.Location = New Point(12 + 5, 12 + 5)
```

needs to be modified to place the labels at different locations.

Perhaps, something like:

```
newText.Location = New Point(12 + 5, 12 + (z * 25))
```

This will vertically align the labels with a gap of 25 between them

Comment: just a few seconds after, but I like your answer better (just change that 15 to 25, because the vertical size of the control is 20)

Comment: I edited the second example of my code to what you suggested and it worked a charm.

It didn't for the first one though, still only displayed the final player name; VB can be strange sometimes lol.

All is good now, thank you ever so much

Answer (score 0):

You are placing them all in the same location

```
newText.Location = New Point(12 + 5, 12 + 5)
```

Use your 'z' index to place them at different locations in order to be able to see them

Answer (score 0):

For me it is easier to contain controls in a `TableLayoutPanel` then add the TLP to what ever control collection, such as a `GroupBox` This way you can couple a Label with TextBox, for example. Here's an example how you can create controls from a DataTable. In your case you would only need 1 ColumnStyle for labels, I just thought I would show you a good practice for future shortcuts. (I rarely use the designer to place controls)

```
    'Start test data
    Dim DtTable As New DataTable
    With DtTable
        Dim NewDtRow As DataRow = .NewRow
        For i As Integer = 0 To 25
            Dim DtCol As New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Col" & i, .DataType = GetType(String)}
            .Columns.Add(DtCol)
            NewDtRow(DtCol.ColumnName) = "Test" & i
        Next
        .Rows.Add(NewDtRow)
    End With
    'End test data

    Dim TLP1 As New TableLayoutPanel With {.Name = "TlpFields"}
    With TLP1
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        .CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset
        .AutoScroll = True
        .AutoSize = True
        .RowStyles.Clear()
        .ColumnStyles.Clear()
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle With {.SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize})
    End With

    For Each DtCol As DataColumn In DtTable.Columns
        With TLP1
            .RowCount += 1
            .RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle With {.SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize})

            'create labels
            .Controls.Add(New Label With {
                                          .Text = DtCol.ColumnName,
                                          .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right}, 0, .RowCount)

            'create textboxs 
            Dim TxtBox As New TextBox With {
                                .Name = "TextBox" & DtCol.ColumnName,
                                .Size = New Size(170, 20),
                                .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left}

            'add binding
            TxtBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", DtTable, DtCol.ColumnName)
            .Controls.Add(TxtBox, 1, .RowCount)
        End With
    Next

    Controls.Add(TLP1)
```